File creation access issues with Gramine Shielded Containers - Intel SGX
I am using Gramine shielded containers(GSC) using which I created signed graminized docker Image. Docker container internally writes some data in to container filesystem. With the original image I am able to successfully run the container, but with GSC, I am getting Permission related to issues while my container trying to write to a file.
I graminized my container image based on GSC documentation https://gramine.readthedocs.io/projects/gsc/en/latest/
I am not sure what I am missing. Is there any specific setting that need to do to make my Graminized docker image work?

Can you add some details: which error message do you have? How are your containers defined? What did you already attempt to fix your issue?
